# Is it useful to delete old answers that no-one found helpful?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

I recently looked at some of my old (> 1 year) answers, which have zero votes against them, and started manually deleting a few them on the grounds that they had not been useful to anyone.

I got to thinking that from a "clutter reduction" perspective this might be something that happens automatically. Does anyone know if it does?

Obviously if "the site" is going to do it for me in the fullness of time then there's no point my doing it manually.

Comment: The site does not delete old, zero- or negative-scoring answers automatically after a set amount of time - that only happens to [*questions*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006). The only automatic *answer* deletions that happen are a result of account deletion, review, or spam/offensive flags.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: Really? I remember something different. Make sure the [meta-tag:FAQ] entries say the same.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha That's for _questions_, we're talking about _answers_ here.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn thx. I was just reading another post on here about peoples' accounts getting blocked, and deleting questions being a contributing factor. Do you know if this is true for answers also? If so, that would be an argument just to leave them alone.

Comment: @PeteH: I believe so. However, if you have many answers, particularly a good portion of which are upvoted and/or accepted, you don't have to worry about that. Your upvoted/accepted answers will speak for you :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just because no one voted your answer/question doesn't mean it wasn't useful in the long run.

Guests from Google do not have accounts, and do not vote, and yet your answer may have helped them.

Never delete your own answer just because you *think* it isn't useful. It's a whole different story when other people tell you it's wrong/harmful/not useful though.

Comment: Yes I suppose so. Personally I always try to mark questions/answers as helpful because that's basically what makes the site work. But I suppose there's nothing to force people to do this.

Comment: @PeteH: Indeed. I have some high voted answers which aren't accepted, and no voted answers which are. Even if your answer is **downvoted**, there's usually no reason to delete it. No one is perfect, and no one knows everything there is to know about any subject.

Comment: I think an exception to this is "me too" answers to an easy question that has an obvious solution. If there are a bunch of similar answers, and others were upvoted and accepted, I don't see any point of leaving mine there.